# Speech/Voice Detection in Audio Files

Tags: classification, object-detection

I have several hundred 30 second long WAVE Files. I need a way to find out, if there are spoken words / voices / speech in them or not.

E.g.: 1.wav no; 2.wav yes; 3.wav no (boolean)
or
1.wav 0.21; 2.wav 0.93; 3.wav 0.13 (likelihood)

My approach is to transform the wave-files into spectograms.
I don't have any labels, so training a Neural Network is out of reach.
The problem: all pre-trained networks focus on speech-to-text.
Does anyone know a solution?